# Automated site scraping for defining all CTA's and Selector Paths/Common Selector Paths within a website

Tags: automation, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, automated-tests, selector

I am looking for a solution for defining all CTA's and Common CTA's within a website. Ideally I would love it to just provide a simple list of common CTA's across the board along with the selector paths, as well as individual CTA's and the selector paths.

Does anyone know of any program/library that may be out there that I can start working with to achieve my goal?

I know of NightWatch.js and a couple others, but nothing as of yet has grabbed my attention. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Comment: There isn't any standard way to mark up a CTA on the web, so I'm not sure how such a library would find those on any given site.

Comment: I am looking for mostly click level CTA's. I thought maybe someone has something built where it would collect every dom node on a page add an event listener and also auto click all the nodes. In theory it would log all the information pertaining to the dom node if indeed an event does occur during the auto-click. Don't you think something like this would be feasible?